# Can an unbounded function have a finite integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am wondering whether there exists a function such that:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$$

at some point $a$ on the real axis but yet,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\ dx<\infty$$

Does the fact that a function is unbounded imply that it has no finite integral?

Comment: Such a function essentially needs to blow up quite slowly at its singularities and decay rapidly as $|x| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{|x|^{1/2}}$ or something like that.

Comment: So this function is unbounded at $x=0$ but still satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\ dx<\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, because the convergence as $|x| \to \infty$ is guaranteed by the exponential. You can use also a function like $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{|x|^{1/2}(1+x^2)}$ if you feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is unbounded at $x=0$, but it has a finite integral $$\int_0^af(x)dx$$ for any positive finite $a$.

Comment: But what about for$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\ dx$

Comment: @john: use a piece wise function. Take thedude's suggestion with $a=1$, then for $x>1$, just use $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$.